# Can many script instances write to tty (parallel)?

Tags: bash, systemd, tty

I have recently migrated my `upstart` scripts to `systemd`, unlike `upstart`, I don't
see any output on the `tty` for services being *started*/*stopped*. To get that visual
feedback, I added something like

```
      echo "Starting $UNIT_NAME" > $MYTTY
```

Where the `MYTTY` is an environment variable I am setting from output of `tty` command.
I have 20 odd services but somehow not all messages were appearing on my tty. So I changed
the line (just to check) to:

```
      echo "Starting $UNIT_NAME" | write myuser $MYTTY
```

And with this, I see all the messages being displayed! (of course, with the additional
`Message from <user>@<hostname> on <term> at <time> ... EOF`

Just to check if `write` is doing something special, I checked the code in `bsdutils` and
I didnt find anything special, its just writing character by character (with some handling
for special chars and CR, LF)

What is wrong with :

```
      echo "Starting $UNIT_NAME" > $MYTTY
```

?
I also tried:

```
      echo -e "Starting $UNIT_NAME\r\b" > $MYTTY
```

etc. But still I don't see messages from all the services on the screen!
Is it because `systemd` starts up all services in *parallel* that some
writes to the tty vanish !?

--

--EDIT--

the following round about way seems to work! but I want to know if
this is safe or is there something better/simpler

```
 mkfifo /tmp/ttyfifo
 (cat > $MYTTY < /tmp/ttyfifo &) && echo -e 'Starting $UNIT_NAME\r\n'  > /tmp/ttyfifo
```

Comment: Why are you not using `journald` for this?

Comment: `journald` does not write to current logged in PTS (say, `/dev/pts/1`). There is a `TTYPath` config, but that is useful only when logged on `console`. For regular user, who  SSHs to the host and lands on a `pts` and manages the services, how can they see the status on the terminal ?

Comment: A daemon shouldn't interact with terminals. The end users should use `systemctl status myservice` and `journalctl -u myservice -b`

Comment: What is the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici I am trying to show the status to the user. And, I want to know if there is a way (or a better way) than what I am trying here. Agree that daemon should not interact with terminals, but in this case a user tries to start/stop a daemon - getting a status output (like `Service X starting...` on the terminal is not wrong! and I would want that feedback)

Comment: You can create an alias to start the service and tail a log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in theory yes , as requests seem to be queued and the descriptor is not locked , you are better off using something like [TTYBUS Multiplexer](https://github.com/danielinux/ttybus) , as concurrent writes to a file/fifo might mess up line breaks etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll read more about this, it seems quite complicated to set up! BTW, do you see anything can go wrong with piping through a temp fifo (the last edit in the question) ? Or is that reliable?

Comment: in the end you should try `&>` instead of `>`  eg. `dooMyFoo &> /tmp/ttyfifo` , because you also want to redirect STDERR , this way you can also mute cronjobs when they are too loud and send mails